# MyBatis invalid column type when using a parameter type int

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm getting the SQLException "Invalid Column Type" whenever I try to use a parameter in my query. The database field "assessment_id" is of type "NUMBER(15)" in oracle.  If I change #{value} to 1 then it works properly and returns my list of Concern objects.  However when I try using this parameter, I get the SQL Exception.  I'm still not sure what to put for the variable name in the XML, I tried using the same name as the variable I'm passing in.

Here is my mapper config.

```
<mapper namespace="ConcernMap">
<resultMap id="ConcernResult" type="com.xxx.name.model.Concern" >
    <result column="insCurrent" property="insCurrent"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="fetchConcernsByWorkflowId" parameterType="int" resultMap="ConcernResult">
    SELECT 
    INSURANCE_CURRENT as insCurrent 
    from KOR_CONCERN where assessment_id = #{value}
</select>
</mapper>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `jdbcType=NUMERIC` to your query

```
SELECT 
INSURANCE_CURRENT as insCurrent 
from KOR_CONCERN where assessment_id = #{value,jdbcType=NUMERIC}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error but using the @Results annotation.

Turns out Mybatis doesn't play nice with Lombok's @Builder and was wrongly identifying the types of the properties of my bean.

Removing the @Builder annotation from the bean solved this issue.